# Cannot explain why SettingWithCopyError is occuring (Python 2.7, Pandas 0.20.3)

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a SettingWithCopyError, and even though I have identified the problem line of code, I can't understand why the error is being raised.

The problem function is as follows:

```
def filter_log(df, search_string):
    results = df.loc[df['Message'].str.contains(search_string)]
    results.loc[:,'Duration'] = results.index.to_series().diff()
    results.loc[:,'Duration'] = results['Duration'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
    results = results.dropna(subset=['Duration'])

    results['Day'] = results.index.floor('d')
    results.loc[:,'Day'] = results['Day'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

    return results
```

The function takes a dataframe and a search string as in input, and returns a filtered/manipulated dataframe as the result.

The error occurs on line 3 - `results.loc[:,'Duration'] = results.index.to_series().diff()`

This line calculates the time increments between each dataframe row using the .diff() method on the datetime index of the input dataframe.

However, I appear to be using .loc indexing correctly, and I shouldn't be setting anything on a copy. Interestingly, the error is only raised the first time I run the script in an interactive environment (or every time I run it standalone). On runs after the first run in an interactive environment, the error does no occur.

The full stack trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-d72a02ad5f86>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/00_Projects/99_Misc/aqis_log_analyser/aqis_log_analyser.py', wdir='C:/00_Projects/99_Misc/aqis_log_analyser')

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 86, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/00_Projects/99_Misc/aqis_log_analyser/aqis_log_analyser.py", line 137, in <module>
    search_results = filter_log(log_df, search_string).loc[start:end]

  File "C:/00_Projects/99_Misc/aqis_log_analyser/aqis_log_analyser.py", line 94, in filter_log
    results.loc[:,'Duration'] = results.index.to_series().diff()

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 179, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 337, in _setitem_with_indexer
    self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2331, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2404, in _set_item
    self._check_setitem_copy()

  File "C:\apps\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1871, in _check_setitem_copy
    raise SettingWithCopyError(t)

SettingWithCopyError: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Any suggestions as to what may be causing the error in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of a `SettingWithCopyError` usually appears several lines before the line mentioned in the traceback. Here, your intention is to copy a subset of `df` into a new DataFrame, modify this new DataFrame, and return it. Pandas isn't sure if you mean to do this, or if you intended to modify the original `df`.

Appending an explicit `.copy()` should eliminate the warning:

```
results = df.loc[df['Message'].str.contains(search_string)].copy()
```

Further reading: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: solved my problem in a split second